# Programatically parse HTML in Node Red

Tags: parsing, node-red

I'd like to parse HTML for all occurrences of <a> and return the values of <a> in an array. I know that I can do that with the help of the HTML Parser node, but I use the results of this parse for another get request and then need to parse again and so on. The chain of "GET-Request -> Parse HTML -> GET-Request -> Parse HTML" is to long and this is ugly somehow.

There is another node parsing JSON and I know that I can call JSON.parse(content) in a function node instead and I guess the same must be possible with HTML as well.So I look for something like HTML.parse(msg.payload, a).

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your first suggestion is the correct answer, just because you think it looks "ugly" doesn't mean it's wrong, it makes it very clear what it's doing at every step.

Comment: Yeah, but just because it is not wrong it is not pretty as well :-) I rather prefer to have a couple lines of code with valuable comments then to have a bunch of nodes where I have to look into.